Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
I'm trying install xinference, and get the message  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'.
I install the Cython with the command pip install Cython ,and install the package from the pypi, the command pip list shows that the package has installed successfully, but it still reports the same error.
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

What's wrong?
Python 3.10.10 Cython 3.0.11 windows 11

You need a C compiler to build that wheel. See also https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/install.html Or try a different Python version for which precompiled Cython wheels are available.
